# Getting build errors in ASP.NET MVC project after migrating to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

I have a project which was developed in **ASP.NET MVC with Visual studio 2013** and which is working fine. Recently we switched to **Visual Studio 2017**, here I'm getting errors while building the same project. The error I'm facing is: "**Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Remote' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**

**I'm facing the above error on [Remote] Attribute, System.Web.Mvc dll(which is the dll for [Remote] attribute) is also there in References folder, but I am still unable to build my project.**

Please help me in get rid of this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to remove and add reference dlls

Comment: Thanks for the response Anoop, I tried already, but still the issue  is existing